# What's the URI path component in websocket used for?

Tags: http, websocket, endpoint

The client initiates a websocket handshake and can specify a custom URI path to use.

```
    GET **/chat** HTTP/1.1
    Host: server.example.com
    Upgrade: websocket
    Connection: Upgrade
    Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
    Origin: http://example.com
    Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat
    Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

The websocket uri takes this form:
[ws-URI = "ws:" "//" host [ ":" port ] path [ "?" query ]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-3)

If I deploy a websocket server listening on `ws://localhost:8080/` and a client connects there with the following uri `ws://localhost:8080/chat`, what's the difference? Why is a path component even necessary? It's there just for load balancing? Or are these "endpoints" isolated?

The following statement in the RFC is quite confusing to me:

The "Request-URI" of the GET method [RFC2616] is used to identify the
endpoint of the WebSocket connection, both to allow multiple domains
to be served from one IP address and to allow multiple WebSocket
endpoints to be served by a single server. ([HERE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.3))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your websocket service always treats every connection identically then there's no need to require a path string, or a query string, in the URI.  (Well, technically you do have to have a path string, but it can be just the single character '/' every time.)

However, if your websocket service wants to be able to provide different content to different clients, then using a path string in the URI can be a convenient way for the clients to indicate what kind of content they're interested in.  Perhaps your chat service offers chat rooms for several different topics, and in that case you might decide to have the client use the path string to indicate the desired topic.  Something like `ws://localhost:8080/sport`, `ws://localhost:8080/politics` or `ws://localhost:8080/cooking`, or you could take it further and have `ws://localhost:8080/sport/football`, `ws://localhost:8080/sport/golf` and `ws://localhost:8080/sport/tennis`, and so on.

> The "Request-URI" of the GET method [RFC2616] is used to identify the
>   endpoint of the WebSocket connection, both to allow multiple domains
>   to be served from one IP address ...

This is just ordinary virtual hosting.  A webserver running at a single IP address can support multiple websites, based on the `host` part of the URI.

> ... and to allow multiple WebSocket endpoints to be served by a single server.

Each of the path examples I gave identifies a different, independent endpoint, all served by your one websocket server.

In this particular example the websocket endpoint is some sort of chat room, but more generally a websocket endpoint is associated with some kind of data feed, often a one-way feed (a websocket might offer a stream of current stock prices for some collection of stocks specified by a URI query string) but potentially a bidirectional feed and potentially an interactive birdirectional feed (like your chat room).

Comment: Thanks for clearing those concepts up. I have some doubts however of how I would go in implementing that logic. It would be a good guess if you know about the Twisted Framework (python) :) You see in the following code snippet the author of the websocket library decides to use the "putChild" interface in behalf of the "File" resource to add the custom websocket path. This, although for a single url path looks enough, I don't see it convenient to create multiple server protocols each for a specific endpoint (and also new instances of the WebsocketServerFactory). Would you recommend (1/2)

Comment: having one server protocol check for the path inside the request instance? And thus this way have different objects or functions implementing the logic for that specific endpoint? Or would you recommend as I described, have several custom server protocols each built for a specific endpoint?https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/blob/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo_site/server.py#L53
(2/2)